# Is there any way to lazy evaluate function.func_name?

Tags: python, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

This question is not about my code
I just want to claim the reason why I need lazy evalution on `function.func_name`

---

I'm using a `curry` decorator in my code
I made it to show curried arguments by modifying func_name
So that when I need some debug, I could easily find out which arguments are already curried

[>>  My modified version <<](https://gist.github.com/zhangyoufu/5495522)
[>> The original version <<](http://mtomassoli.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/currying-in-python/)

Example of my `curry`:

```
@curry
def f(a, b, c, flag_foo=True, flag_bar=False):
    pass

>>> f
<function f at 0x100545398>

>>> f(1, flag_bar=True)
<function f(1, flag_bar=True) at 0x1005451b8>

>>> f(1, flag_bar=True)(3, flag_foo=False)
<function f(1, 3, flag_foo=False, flag_bar=True) at 0x1004aee60>
```

---

Since the `func_name` will never be accessed without debugging,
I want to avoid the overhead of the evalution of func_name

However, `function` is a final class that cannot be subclassed
Is there any way to perform lazy evaluation on `function.func_name`?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: I believe in this complex situations is simply better to make `curry` a class and replace the function with an object with its own `__str__` and `__repr__` that do what you want. This also allow any lazy evaluation since you can use things such as properties/getters.

Comment: I've tried various hacks, and it doesn't look like it's possible to mess with a function object to achieve this in Python, although you might be able to do it with an extension module. But, I'd go with the idea @Bakuriu suggested. If you define a `__call__` method on a class, then you can use an instance as if it were a function.

Comment: Do you have reason to assume that this is a bottleneck? The solution will be quite complex, so I assume it's not worth it.

Comment: @Bakuriu You're right. I double-checked both `function` and `str`. There is no way to perform hacks on them. A functor would save my life.

Comment: @delnan Nope. I just wondering if this is restricted by language/implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
class Curried(object):
    def __init__(self, func, args=None, kwargs=None):
        self._func = func
        self._args = () if args is None else args[:]
        self._kwargs = {} if kwargs is None else dict(kwargs)
        self._name = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or kwargs:
            return Curried(self._func,
                           self._args + args,
                           dict(self._kwargs.items() + kwargs.items()))
        else:
            return self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        if self._name is None:
            self._name = self._get_curried_name()
        return self._name

    def _get_curried_name(self):
        _args = ([str(a) for a in self._args] +
                 ['{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self._kwargs.iteritems()])
        all_args = ", ".join(_args)
        return '<curried {}({}) at 0x{:x}>'.format(
            self._func.func_name, all_args, id(self))

    def curry(func):
        _curried = Curried(func)
        return _curried
```

Test:

```
@curry
def f(a, b, c, flag_foo=True, flag_bar=False):
    return 'horray!'

print f
print f(1, 2, flag_bar=True)
print f(1, 2, flag_bar=True)(3, flag_foo=False)
print f(1, 2, flag_bar=True)(3, flag_foo=False)()
```

And the result:

```
<curried f() at 0x100484210>
<curried f(1, 2, flag_bar=True) at 0x100484250>
<curried f(1, 2, 3, flag_bar=True, flag_foo=False) at 0x100484310>
horray!
```

Instead of a "pure" function, here you get a callable class that acts as a function. You evaluate the name only once. Of course, if you want `func_name` you can add such variable as [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and return `str(self)` which is evaluated once

Comment: Yup, `__call__` is the only way to perform this. `_kwags` looks like a typo. Thanks!